# Jaeger : how to see logs on Jaeger UI?

Tags: jaeger

I have installed Jaeger setup and I want to see logs in Jaeger UI from some of my microservices which are in golang. For that I have added code in one my file as follows:

```
import(
    "github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go"
    "github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go/log"
)

Log.Debugf("Level: %d, Traversing slice %s length=%d\n", parentBag.Level, name, length)
span := opentracing.StartSpan("Jager Console Print " + name)
span.LogFields(
    log.String("event", "string-format"),
    log.String("value", name),
    )
 span.SetTag("Jager Console Print", name)
 defer span.Finish()
}
```

But it didn't work for me